# What is the File's Owner (in Interface builder)?

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nib

I am new to Cocoa and I don't understand the concept of `File's Owner` of a .nib file.

Here is the way I would see things :

- Consider a file `myNibFile.nib` file that describes how a window looks.
- Now, I want to connect an actual window to this .nib file. So, I create a class `myWindow`, which is a subclass of `NSWindowController`. And, to do this connection, I change the `init` method like this:

  ```
       -(id)init
       {
           [super initWithWindowNibName:@"myNibFile"];
           return self;
       }
  ```

So, I understand that when I create an instance of `myWindow`, the "system" will go and look at the .nib file and create the adequate object.

So, my question are :

- why do I have to specify that the `File's Owner` of my .nib file is `myWindow` ? Isn't it redundant ?
- I guess it means I didn't really understood what the `File's Owner`. What is it ? Why does the .nib file have to belong to something ? Can't it be "somewhere" in my "application" and when it is needed, the "system" goes there and use it ?

Thanks for helping me to see more clearly in these new concepts !

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Two points to be remembered:

- The File owner is the object that loads the nib, i.e. that object which receives the message `loadNibNamed:` or `initWithNibName:`.
- If you want to access any objects in the nib after loading it, you can set an outlet in the file owner.

So you created a fancy view with lots of buttons, subviews etc . If you want to modify any of these views / objects any time after loading the nib FROM the loading object (usually a view or window controller) you set outlets for these objects to the file owner. It's that simple.

This is the reason why by default all View Controllers or Window Controllers act as file owners, and also have an outlet to the main window or view object in the nib file: because duh, if you're controlling something you'll definitely need to have an outlet to it so that you can send messages to it.

The reason it's called file owner and given a special place, is because unlike the other objects in the nib, the file owner is external to the nib and is not part of it. In fact, it only becomes available when the nib is loaded. So the file owner is a stand-in or proxy for the actual object which will later load the nib.

Hope you've understood. I'll clarify any of the points if you ask.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The last paragraph is the most important for me: the File's Owner is not part of the nib.

The answer 'you need outlets...' is not valid for me because the outlets can belong to an object that you add to you NIB.

My idea that you can link (and actually *have to*) an object and a NIB via the code (`loadNibNamed`, etc.) and so that you don't need the redundant link `File's Owner` is true but then : how will you do to connect the outlets to this object ? You answer this point.

Comment: I was waiting for a satisfying answer ! Maybe you could reorganise your answer to emphasize on the last paragraph. Thanks. I hope my last comment is clear.

Comment: Isn't it the NSNib object that receives `loadNibNamed:` or `initWithNibName:`? Then File's Owner is given as an argument to the method that actually instantiates the NIB.

Answer (score 10):

The fundamental thing to understand is that Interface Builder allows you to create objects that are automatically connected to each other, with no effort on the part of your program.  You can instantiate all kinds of objects including non-view ones, and they can be inter-related; for example, you might create the instance of a table view data source along with the view itself, etc.  This mechanism is commonly used to create an Application Delegate within your Main Menu NIB.

However, since it's all done via drag&drop, it seems there is no way that you can form a connection between any of the NIB objects and the objects that already exist in your application, with one exception.

When code is loading the NIB file, you have the option to specify exactly *one* object which the NIB will consider to be the "Files Owner".  This is the placeholder that you see inside Interface Builder; since it can represent any object within your application, Interface Builder can't know what actions/outlets are available on it.  This is why you can modify the "class" of the Files Owner, in the Attributes tab.

Files Owner does not really represent "ownership" or "parenthood".  What it represents is "the object that loaded this NIB".

Comment: I still don't understand, since how I really call the NIB from my program is with `initWithWindowNibName:@"myNibFile"`. With this instruction, I create the connection between the NIB and other objects.

Answer (score 0):

File's Owner is a placeholder in IB so all the outlets and actions in your code are "linkable" in IB, you can control-drag to connect stuff on the screen to the code.

Answer (score 0):

File's Owner in Interface Builder is so that it knows the object type of the parent. This is used in two ways. Firstly, in Interface Builder so that IB knows what outlets and actions are available to you to connect. Secondly it is used by the application framework to know how to reconnect things to the rest of your code once the nib file is loaded.